# Evaluating a trig limit with reciprocal

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Evaluate the following limit:
$$\lim_{\Theta \rightarrow 0}6\Theta \operatorname{cosec}(3\Theta) $$

My solution:

$$\eqalign{\lim_{\Theta \rightarrow 0}6\Theta \times \frac{1}{\sin(3\Theta) }&=
\lim_{\Theta \rightarrow 0}6\Theta \times\frac{1}{\sin(3\Theta) }.\frac{3\Theta }{3\Theta }\\
&=\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0}\frac{6\Theta}{3\Theta}\\
&=2}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes...but you can shorten it: $$6\theta\csc3\theta=2\frac{3\theta}{\sin3\theta}\xrightarrow[\theta\to 0]{}2\cdot 1=2$$ +1

Comment: Yes, but if you know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{\sin x}=1$, you might as well rewrite the limit as $2\lim \frac{x}{\sin x}$, which is even more straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's absolutely fine, but there's no need to multiply by $\frac{3 \Theta}{3\Theta}$.

Just skip that bit and note that, in the limit as $\Theta \to 0, \sin(3\Theta) \equiv3\Theta$, so $\lim\limits_{\Theta\to 0}\left[\frac{6\Theta}{\sin(3\Theta)}\right]= \require{cancel}\frac{6\cancel{\Theta}}{3\cancel{\Theta}} \equiv \boxed{2}$.